# How to show the center of a background image when the screen is resized in CSS/React JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am creating a website using React JS and I want it to have a background image with fixed height and width and when the screen is resized, the center of the image is shown. But what I have is that the left side is showing from the image when the screen is resized. Here is the JSX and CSS code.

JSX

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="screens-container"> 
          <div className="image-container">
            <img className="background-img" src={background} alt=""></img>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.screens-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.background-img {
  height: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: if you want to have an image background, the better way is to set background-image property in .image-container class rather than <img> element

Comment: Yeah I did that and it worked, thanks